# Attempting to implement LocationListener in Android Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am attempting to currently create an Android app that will follow a user's route of travel. Although at this point I am simply attempting to get their current location. I have attempted several methods involving LocationListeners and the like, but either get no result or errors that the guide never mentions. Some use it in the HTML5 pages but I don't really know enough to do it that way. Below I have the code that, in theory, should get the user's location and place a marker there.

Admittedly there are a lot of imports, mostly from me stumbling my way through this project and trying different locations to other problems that have popped up. The end result will be that the user completes a perimeter of something and it will get the area. While getting the area from a series of LatLngs is doable, the problem is getting the actual perimeter drawn by the user walking it. I am hoping to, at the moment, get the user's location repeatedly into a list of LatLngs and use that, but I am open to other suggestions.

```
    package ideo.farmerhelp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.app.Activity;

    import java.io.FileDescriptor;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzc;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzl;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
    import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnMarkerDragListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, android.location.LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
        TextView tv;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        TextView txtlat;
        String lat;
        String provider;
        protected String latitude, longitude;
        protected boolean gps_Enabled, network_enabled;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //On map create
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentById(R.id.map); //Create a support map fragment
                   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.area);

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,  0, ll); //Requests that I cast the fourth parameter to android.location.LocationListener, doing so results in a castexception.



        }
}
```

Comment: Check this github link https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/LocationManager.java

Comment: Unfortunately attempting to implement the code in there didn't result in anything happening. As far as I can tell, either the extends I'm using doesn't work with this, or the issue is that I'm having trouble passing the content of a variable from the inner class to a method in the outside class.

Comment: The full code is here: https://gist.github.com/MaxKojote/bdbeadac035396e18408